# Distribution of $F(X)$ where $F$ is the distribution function of a continuous random variable $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable such that it's distribution function $F(x):=P(X \le x)$ is continuous.

Then is it true that $F(X)$ follows a uniform distribution ?

I can show this if $F$ is differentiable, but otherwise I'm not sure.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it follows a uniform distribution.

We know that $F$ is non-decreasing, and we can further note that

$$P(F(X) \leq x) = P(X \in \{y \mid F(y) \leq x\})$$

Now set $M = \sup\{y \mid F(y) \leq x\} $ so that by continuity, we can obtain $F(M) = x$. It follows that $P(F(X) \leq x) = x$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$. In other words, $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: From $F(M)=x$ how did it follow $P(F(X) \le x)=x$ for $0\le x \le 1$?

Comment: $M$ is the largest value for which $F(y)\leq x$ holds. Does that clear things up for you?

Comment: Um not really ... I'm still not able to make the connection ...

Comment: @user521337 Try making a plot of the CDF for a discrete random variable.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, consider that $F$ is absolutely continuous and strictly monotone. Then the random variable $U = F_{X}(x)$ has distribution given by
\begin{align*}
G_{U}(u) = \textbf{P}(U\leq u) = \textbf{P}(F_{X}(x)\leq u) = \textbf{P}(x \leq F^{-1}_{X}(u)) = F_{X}(F^{-1}_{X}(u)) = u
\end{align*}

from whence we conclude $U = F_{X}(x)$ has uniform distribution.